# How to configure remote Helm repo in Artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

we have two Artifactories.

Artifactory 1 (artifactory.local.com) has a local Helm repo, which is working perfectly. You can reach it with helm and download Helm Charts without problems.

Artifactory 2 (artifactory.local.cloud) has a local Helm repo, a remote Helm repo (artifactory.local.com) and a virtual Helm repo, combine the first two repositories.

Then we have a Rundeck server, running Helm. There's only one repo configured, artifactory.local.cloud. It can only reach this repo, because of network routing.

When installing Helm charts from the local repo on artifactory.local.cloud, there's no problem.

BUT chart from artifactory.local.com cannot be retrieved. The problem is that Helm is trying to get them from the first artifactory(.local.com) and there's no network route to this one. 
Helm repo update is not helping. The index.yml of the virtual helm repo is also pointing to the other Artifactory for this packages. I think that is the cause. But I don't know how to fix this. Can anybody help?

Both Artifactories are installed in version 6.12.

I hope my description is understandable :D
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing here is a smart remote repository - more information in this link - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Smart+Remote+Repositories
Did you configure the remote repository with the "/api/helm/" part in the path? For example - "http://art.local:8081/artifactory/api/helm/helm-local" - this is the correct configuration.
In addition, from your description, I understood that Artifactory 2 can not reach Artifactory 1 because of network restrictions - if this is really the case, no configuration you do will make this work, and you will need to configure a route between those two instances.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Apperently my description was missleading. Artifactory 1 can not be reached by the Rundeck server. So the Rundeck server is contacting Artifacotry 2 which is telling him to download the package from Artifactory 1. And this, he can't reach because of network restrictions.
I'll check the other thing you mentioned regarding the URL.

Comment: I just tried to create a Smart Remote Repository, like described in the link you provided. I always get a 404 not found. 
The documentation does not mention if you need to enable it on the remote side. Maybe there's a setting missing?
Edit: When entering the URL-string without api/helm, like already configured the test is returning ok. But in this way it only works as mentioned above.